# (PHPWord 0.12.0) What means : Temp folder "/var/folders/sg/t6c_xdnj5rgb547lb5nb1rrh0000gn/T" is writable ... failed

Tags: php, phpword

I'm not used to work with Php Libs, and i don't know how to fix the error :

Temp folder "/var/folders/sg/t6c_xdnj5rgb547lb5nb1rrh0000gn/T" is writable ... failed

I used a MacBook pro 10.10.3 and XAMPP, I hope this lib works well with Apple OS.

A preview would be really appreciated, infos.

Thanks for help!

Comment: i think that's related to phpword, whatever it's used for. you'll need to take a peek at library code or google the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks. Really hard to get infos,  i see.

Comment: Sounds like insufficient rights or invalid temp path... PhpWord uses sys_get_temp_dir(); method to get the php temporary folder on your system - i.e. you can either try to modify the used directory rights, or alternatively you can define the temp folder that PhpWord is using by simple calling the static method setTempDir($dir)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the 'write' permission to Temp folder "/var/folders/sg/t6c_xdnj5rgb547lb5nb1rrh0000gn/T". So the PHPWord could write a temp file to that folder.
It is simply a permission issue. Good luck!